# Retrieving stack trace of launch intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activitymanager

I have a React Native app running on Android and using some libraries that I have recently added. Now the app is constantly reopening itself after a couple of seconds whenever I close it without completely killing it via the back stack.

Logcat is printing an infinite loop of commands that are temporarily suspended when closing the app and then resume the moment the app starts again, including this ever repeating line:

```
08-21 12:21:05.099   776  2791 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10200000 cmp=app.myapp/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10182 on display 0
```

I am trying to find out what is causing this intent to be created over and over again. The uid `10182` is my app's.

How can I learn more / find the command that is launching this? Is there a way to get a stack trace for this particular ActivityManager log? Or how would you go about debugging this?

This is the log that is repeating infinitely:

> 08-21 14:34:24.823   776  3589 I ActivityManager: START u0
>   {flg=0x10200000 cmp=app.coffeechat/.MainActivity (has extras)} from
>   uid 10182 on display 0
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.832 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: onHostResume
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.832 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: App is now visible
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.833 31551 31619 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] Sync
>   already in progress.
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.838 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: onHostPause
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.838 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: App is now not
>   visible
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.823   776  3589 I ActivityManager: START u0
>   {flg=0x10200000 cmp=app.coffeechat/.MainActivity (has extras)} from
>   uid 10182 on display 0
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.832 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: onHostResume
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.832 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: App is now visible
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.833 31551 31619 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] Sync
>   already in progress.
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.838 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: onHostPause
>
> 08-21 14:34:24.838 31551 31551 D ReactNativeNotifs: App is now not
>   visible

and so on.

Comment: might be crashing, usually apps reopen on crashes

Comment: It's not reporting a crash, neither as a dialog nor as a stacktrace in the logs. Could it be a crash anyway? I edited the question with the loop I am getting.

Comment: yes it can be a crash anyway.... i have seen crash logs vanish on app restart many times.... what i would suggest is posting logs in your code and see where the logs stop printing....